# How difficult is to migrate to new PC case

Tags: graphics-card

I have a cheap PC clone that works for me. I was given a GEFORCE GTX 970 PCIe graphics card but it doesn't fit. How complicated is to move everything to a new, larger case? The best to you all. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't fit"?

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial.

Assuming you have a normal PC (not sme A-brand who likes to customise things or a server) then it is like moving lego bricks from one case to another.

The trick is to make sure you do it carefully and do not dammage anything (e.g. do not wear a woolen sweater and rubber shoes). But the technical aspect is really trivial.

Only potential challenges are:

- Case is tiny and components do not fit (HTPC case, SFF caes, ...)
- Case is too small for a card (lengthwise, though this is rare. standard cases fit standard cards).
- Custum MB factor (servers, Dell, HP, ... rather then normal)
- Custom PSU factor (again on Dells, HPs, ....)
- Possible lack or difference of slots (e.g. no frot USB plug on the new case). In which case  it will still work.